# Android app about page

Tags: android

I have an app that has three tabs. They all do specific things. I need to add an about page to specify some of the free tools used in the app. Where do you add an about page for the app in Android? Is there a convention?

Couple thoughts are

1. I could add a new tab but I intend to add another tab or two to the app, so may be not a good idea.
2. Could add as a menu item, but not sure which tab's menu items should the about page be... coz like I said, each tab handles a specific task in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just put it in one tab that uses the free tools. I agree with the other answers, doesn't seem to be a size fits all scenario available here.

Answer (score 1):

From a design perspective, I don't think there is a convention for this.  That being said, I'd say adding it to each page's options menu would make the the most sense if you don't want to use a tab.  If you can only access the About page from certain other pages, that may be confusing to users.

Answer (score 1):

You Could use TextView as the link of the item and custom dialog for showing the content. It will work like you wanna show licences, then Text will be license and onClick it will show the custom dialog box with the dialog contents.

Answer (score 0):

You could also put an information button (i) in the main page of your application, and when you click the button a flip transition to see the about page.

Hope this helps...

Comment: The "i" button is in iOS right @oriolpons? I don't think I saw it in Android. Tried looking it up but nothing came up on the web. I'm targeting Android 2.1 by the way (API level 7)